# How to uninstall Grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have Windows 8 pre-installed, and then I installed GRUB with Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not my thing, so now I want to remove it along with GRUB. From what I have learned, with UEFI, GRUB does not overwrite the Windows bootloader in the EFI partition and is stored elsewhere.

**How would I remove GRUB and make my PC use the Windows bootloader instead?**

It should be noted that I created a separate /boot partition when installing Ubuntu.

Comment: The same question was asked 8 years and 5 months ago. See @guiverc 's link.

Answer (score 1):

If you created a separate boot partition during install it should be sufficient to remove that and the Ubuntu partition. But let it boot into Windows first, then remove the partitions.